# ASP.NET MVC2 - Java Stocks style documentation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there anything similar to JavaDocs for ASP.NET MVC2 using the Visual Studio 2010 PRO IDE?

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The de-facto standard for documentation on .NET is using [XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/may/documenting-your-code-with-xml-comments) inside the code. Simply position your cursor just before the method declaration and type `///`. Visual Studio will automatically infer the arguments and generate the necessary section which you could fill. Then simply enable XML documentation:

[image]

If you want to generate some MSDN style documentation from the resulting XML file here are some tools you could use:

- [SandCastle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sandcastle/)
- [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)